# Path connectedness of graph and domain implies continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to produce an example to show that a path-connected graph $G_f$ of a function $f$ whose domain is also path-connected does not imply the function is continuous.

Does this example work:

Consider The function $f:[\theta,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where $f$ is defined in the following way:

$f(\theta) = (cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$ for $0 < \theta < 2\pi,$

$f(0) = (0,1),$

and $f(2\pi) = (0,-1).$

The graph produced is a circle without the point $(0,1).$ Moreover, it is has a jump discontinuity at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi.$ However, the domain $[0,2\pi]$ and the graph are path connected.

Is there an error somewhere? I doubt myself...

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $f : [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb R^2$, instead of $f : [\theta,2\pi] \to \mathbb R$? Other than that, this looks fine.

Comment: Hey! Ya. Excuse me. That's what I mean:) Thanks, Lee!

Comment: The image of $f$ seems to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I forgot to change that! Changed:) thanks!

Comment: Does it make sense otherwise?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud I think you are confusing the graph of $f$ with its image. As it stands, the graph of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and is not path connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example does not work because, as said in comments you are confusing the graph of $f$ with it's image. The graph of a function $f:X\to Y$ is the subset of $X\times Y$ defined by $$G_f=\{(x,f(x)), x\in X\}$$ and in your example it is not connected.

An easy example of a disctontinuous function with path connected graph, and defined on  a path connected set, is the logarithm

Set $X=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and $f:X\to \mathbb C$ given by a determination of the logarithm, namely for any complex number $z$ you choose the polar coordinates with $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ (i.e. set $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$) and define

$$f(z)=f(\rho e^{i\theta})=\log(\rho)+i\theta.$$

This function is not continuous on positive reals numbers (where $\theta=0$). However, its graph is path connected because because for any two points $z,w\in X$ you can connnect them with an arc not passing trhough $\mathbb R^+$ (except maybe at endpoints) and this produce a path in the graph connecting $(z,f(z))$ to $(w,f(w))$.

Comment: I don't see why it is discontinuous, are you sure?

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon $f(1)=0$, $1=\lim_{\theta\to 2\pi} e^{i\theta}$ but $\lim_{\theta\to 2\pi}f(e^{i\theta})=2\pi i$

Comment: This is true, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Let $C$ be the unit circle, which is path connected. Define $f:C \to \mathbb R$ by setting $f(e^{it})=t,0\le t <2\pi.$ Then $f$ is discontinuous at $(1,0).$ However the graph of $f$ is the spiral $\{(e^{it},t):0\le t <2\pi\},$ which is path connected.

Comment: Great answer!  This answer really deserves the bounty. It is much simpler than the other answer (whose graph is a subset of $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$). Here the graph of $f$, $G_f \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ and can easily be visualized!

Comment: @SelrachDunbar Thank you!